# Using an overlapped element to create drag-zoom effect on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, draggable, mask

I have this mockup:

[image]

where the white button lets you drag the iPhone mockup to the left and right, giving a distorted/zoomed perspective of the image in the background.

The drag functionality works, what I'm looking for is a solution that gives the distorted/zoomed view in the iPhone-mockup. I've been fiddling with the `mask`-property, but can't achieve what I want.

jQuery, JS, CSS, SCSS solutions are welcome.

(The image in the code isn't the exact same as the one in the mockup, ignore that)

#### Snippet

**(works best in full page view)**

```js
let draggable = $('.phone-mockup-container'); //element
let dragTrigger = $('.phone-trigger');
dragTrigger.on('mousedown', function(e) {
  let dr = draggable.addClass("drag");
  height = dr.outerHeight();
  width = dr.outerWidth();
  max_left = dr.parent().offset().left + dr.parent().width() - dr.outerWidth();
  min_left = dr.parent().offset().left;
  xpos = dr.offset().left + width - e.pageX;
  $(document.body).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    let ileft = e.pageX + xpos - width;

    if (dr.hasClass("drag")) {
      if (ileft <= min_left) {
        ileft = min_left;
      }
      if (ileft >= max_left) {
        ileft = max_left;
      }
      dr.offset({
        left: ileft
      });
    }
  }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    dr.removeClass("drag");
  });
});
```

```css
.phone-mockup-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.phone-mockup-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  max-width: 355px;
}

.phone-mockup {
  -o-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
}

.phone-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  max-width: fit-content;
  font-size: 29px;
  padding: 13px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: move;
}

.image {
  max-width: 820px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phone-mockup-wrapper">
  <div class="phone-mockup-container">
    <img class="phone-mockup" src="https://i.ibb.co/NpXQY30/iphone-mockup.png">
    <span class="phone-trigger">drag</span>
  </div>
</div>
<img class="image" src="https://i.ibb.co/MPwGfmc/7e8db8b589fe8defd6b9cc051a676a19.png">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using the same image as `background-image` and a combination of `background-size`, `overflow` and the value generated from the function that lets you drag the iPhone-mockup.

```js
let draggable = $('.phone-mockup-container');
let dragTrigger = $('.phone-trigger');
let eller = $('.phone-area');

dragTrigger.on('mousedown', function(e) {
  eller.addClass('dragger');

  let dr = draggable.addClass("drag");
  height = dr.outerHeight();
  width = dr.outerWidth();
  max_left = dr.parent().offset().left + dr.parent().width() - dr.outerWidth();
  min_left = dr.parent().offset().left;
  xpos = dr.offset().left + width - e.pageX;
  $(document.body).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    let ileft = e.pageX + xpos - width;

    if (dr.hasClass("drag")) {
      if (eller.hasClass("dragger")) {

        if (ileft <= min_left) {
          ileft = min_left;
        }
        if (ileft >= max_left) {
          ileft = max_left;
        }

        dr.offset({
          left: ileft
        });
        let test = document.querySelector('.drag');
        let left = test.style.left;
        $(eller).css('backgroundPositionX', '-' + left);
      }
    }
  }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    dr.removeClass("drag");
    eller.removeClass("dragger");
  });
});
```

```css
.phone-mockup-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.phone-mockup-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  max-width: 355px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.phone-mockup {
  -o-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.phone-area {
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/MPwGfmc/7e8db8b589fe8defd6b9cc051a676a19.png');
  position: absolute;
  top: 4.3%;
  top: 1.2%;
  left: 5%;
  height: 97%;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 820px 709px;
  background-position: left;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.phone-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  max-width: fit-content;
  font-size: 29px;
  padding: 13px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
}

.image {
  max-width: 820px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phone-mockup-wrapper">
  <div class="phone-mockup-container">
    <img class="phone-mockup" src="https://i.ibb.co/NpXQY30/iphone-mockup.png">
    <div class="phone-area"></div>
    <span class="phone-trigger">drag</span>
  </div>
</div>
<img class="image" src="https://i.ibb.co/MPwGfmc/7e8db8b589fe8defd6b9cc051a676a19.png">
```